# Maximum numer of HTTP post request that can be sent to Apache PHP script at a time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `PHP` script which accepts `HTTP` post requests processes data and send the processed request back via `Curl`. There is no other option possible to send data from the application.

The problem is application which sends the `HTTP POST` sends a large number of request `min (10000)` at a time. I am logging all the request that comes in and some `POST` request are not reaching the server (In the latest test case I sent `728 requests` and `52` never reached the server.).

I am lost as to why this is happening. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything logged to the server's error log?

Comment: You might need to [tune apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html) to be able to accept / have more concurrent connections. (Or Nginx / web server in use )

Comment: @NicoHaase the issue is they did reach the server at all, hence nothing in error logs

Comment: This looks more like a configuration/server issue and not a coding problem.

Comment: Are you really sure they didn't reach the server? How should this be possible?

Comment: Doesn't apache have a baked-in `maxclients` number of 256?

Comment: @NigelRen I am not an expert in server configuration any idea what to configure

Comment: I'm not an expert in server configuration, but SO is more about coding problems.  So not sure if this is the best place to ask how to tune the server/architecture.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am 100% sure they did not reach the server.

Comment: "application which sends the HTTP POST", and "I am 100% sure they did not reach the server. ". If both those statements are true, then you have a networking issue.